# setInterval not working when create a slideshow efffect with for loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, setinterval

I want to create a slideshow using setInterval to run auto, but I don't see it iterate!

After each 2s: slide 1 -> slide 2 -> slide 1 -> slide 2 ->...

This is my code:

```
// debugger;
var getValue1 = document.querySelectorAll(".slide.slide-1 span");
var getValue2 = document.querySelectorAll(".slide.slide-2 span");
var slide = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
var autoRunSlider = setInterval(function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < slide.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < getValue1.length; j++) {
            getValue1[j].style.transform = "rotateX(90deg) translateY(-50%)";
            getValue2[j].style.transform = "rotateX(0deg) translateY(0)";

        }
        // if (i >= slide.length - 1) {
        //     for (let j = 0; j < getValue1.length; j++) {
        //         getValue2[j].style.transform = "rotateX(90deg) translateY(-50%)";
        //         getValue1[j].style.transform = "rotateX(0deg) translateY(0)";
        //     }
        // }
    }
}, 2000);
```

link codepen.io: [slideshow](https://codepen.io/huyhoangepu997/pen/jgqqgB)

Comment: Well it's working for me, which browser are you using ?

Comment: @DylanKas I am using Chrome, bit it doesn't iterate. slide 1 -> slide 2 -> slide 1 -> slde 2 ->...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you only setting the transitions for moving slide1 to slide2. You need to add transitions for moving slide 2 back to slide 1.

```
// debugger;
var getValue1 = document.querySelectorAll(".slide.slide-1 span");
var getValue2 = document.querySelectorAll(".slide.slide-2 span");
var slideIndex = 0;
var slide = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
var autoRunSlider = setInterval(function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < slide.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < getValue1.length; j++) {
          if (slideIndex === 0) {
            getValue1[j].style.transform = "rotateX(90deg) translateY(-50%)";
            getValue2[j].style.transform = "rotateX(0deg) translateY(0)";
          } else {
             getValue1[j].style.transform = "";
             getValue2[j].style.transform = "";
          }

        }
        // if (i >= slide.length - 1) {
        //     for (let j = 0; j < getValue1.length; j++) {
        //         getValue2[j].style.transform = "rotateX(90deg) translateY(-50%)";
        //         getValue1[j].style.transform = "rotateX(0deg) translateY(0)";
        //     }
        // }
    }
    slideIndex = slideIndex === 0 ? 1 : 0;
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Thank you. But I want the slides to run only in one direction. A circle

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are setting the transitions once and never reset them again. So the loop runs and triggers the same transition for each element, that's why the animation only runs once.

You have to reset the animation on the elements that are not visible so that you can animate those again in the next loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try move look out of `setInterval`

```
var getValue1 = document.querySelectorAll(".slide.slide-1 span");
var getValue2 = document.querySelectorAll(".slide.slide-2 span");
var slide = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
var slideNum = 0;
var autoRunSlider = setInterval(function() {
    for (let j = 0; j < getValue1.length; j++) {
        getValue1[j].style.transform = "rotateX(90deg) translateY(-50%)";
        getValue2[j].style.transform = "rotateX(0deg) translateY(0)";
    }
    slideNum++;
    if (slideNum >= slide.length) {
      clearInterval(autoRunSlider);
    }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But it run once!

Comment: so what's the `getValue1.length` ?

Comment: 4 span tag, 4 parts of a slider

Answer (score 1):

You need to reverse the effect, since setting the `transform` property multiple times only works once.

```js
// debugger;
let effect1 = true; // Counter for choosing which effect to take
var getValue1 = document.querySelectorAll(".slide.slide-1 span");
var getValue2 = document.querySelectorAll(".slide.slide-2 span");
var slide = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
var autoRunSlider = setInterval(function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < slide.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < getValue1.length; j++) {
          if (effect1) {
            getValue1[j].style.transform = "rotateX(90deg) translateY(-50%)";
            getValue2[j].style.transform = "rotateX(0deg) translateY(0)";
          } else { // Reverse the effect
            getValue2[j].style.transform = "rotateX(90deg) translateY(-50%)";
            getValue1[j].style.transform = "rotateX(0deg) translateY(0)";
          }
        }
    }
    effect1 = !effect1
}, 2000);
```